# How to run BAT file outside of installation location using wix installer?

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, wix, wix3

I want to deploy a service to tomcat server while installation, To do so I have to stop the tomcat and then start it. Tomcat has own bat files to start/stop.

Using Wix installer I want to call that bat file from tomcat (Got tomcat location using environment variable) to stop it and then can deploy service on it.

I am a bit new to Wix Installer, Please let me know if any more inputs required.

@StevenScott and @KenWhite I tried below:

I created a test bat file to check whether its invoking or not, this bat file will generate a new txt file if executed. This is not executing bat file even though it created a BATCHRUN property and setting value as I can see in log file.

```
<Property Id="BATCHRUN">
      <DirectorySearch Id="TestBat" Path="D:\DIR_Test" Depth="1">
        <FileSearch Id="BatExecute" Name="abc.bat"  />
      </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
<CustomAction Id="BatchScript" Property="BATCHRUN" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="no" Return="check" ExeCommand="/c D:\DIR_Test\abc.bat" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="BatchScript" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Also, I tried to execute below code sample it's not getting build, **Error is** *"The Directory with Id 'TESTDIR' is not a valid root directory.  There may only be a single root directory per product or module and its Id attribute value must be 'TARGETDIR' and its Name attribute value must be 'SourceDir'."*

```
<Directory Id="TESTDIR" Name="TestDir" src="D:\DIR_Test"></Directory>
<CustomAction Id="test1" ExeCommand="[TESTDIR]\abc.bat" Directory="TESTDIR" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncWait"/>
```

My requirement is very simple, just after prerequisite check I need to stop Tomcat and after deployment, I need to start Tomcat. Please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried?  Try to show what you are trying and what is not working, so someone can help correct your issue, as oppose to trying to do the whole thing for you.  This leads to better answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: Then all you have to do is change INSTALLLOCATION to the actual location that the bat files are located, right? What's stopping you from doing so?